# PHP SoapClient WSDL DeserializationFailed Invalid enum value

Tags: php, enums, wsdl, soap-client

I am trying to use SoapClient in PHP to retrieve data from a WSDL. If I use hardcoded values, then it works with zero errors:

```
$client = new SoapClient(someWSDLUrl);
$params2 = array();
$params2['AuthenticationKey'] = $obj->{'LoginResult'}; 
$params2['VehicleClass'] = 'UsedCar';
$params2['ApplicationCategory'] = 'Consumer';
$params2['VersionDate'] = '2016';
$result2 = $client->GetMakes($params2);
```

I am getting the following error when I use variables or dynamic content:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:DeserializationFailed
] The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter 
http://someURL/VehicleInformationService:VehicleClass
. The InnerException message was 'Invalid enum value 'UsedCars'
```

I have tried

```
$client = new SoapClient(someWSDLUrl);
$params2 = array();
$params2['AuthenticationKey'] = $obj->{'LoginResult'}; 
$params2['VehicleClass'] = $VehicleClass;
$params2['ApplicationCategory'] = $ApplicationCategory;
$params2['VersionDate'] = $VersionDate;
$result2 = $client->GetMakes($params2);
```

I have also tried

```
$client = new SoapClient(someWSDLUrl);
$params2 = array();
$params2['AuthenticationKey'] = (string) $obj->{'LoginResult'}; 
$params2['VehicleClass'] = (string) $VehicleClass;
$params2['ApplicationCategory'] = (string) $ApplicationCategory;
$params2['VersionDate'] = (string) $VersionDate;
$result2 = $client->GetMakes($params2);
```

I have also tried:

```
$SubmitData = new stdClass();
$SubmitData->AuthenticationKey = new SoapVar($obj->{'LoginResult'}, XSD_STRING);
$SubmitData->VehicleClass = new SoapVar($VehicleClass, XSD_STRING);
$SubmitData->ApplicationCategory = new SoapVar($ApplicationCategory, XSD_STRING);
$SubmitData->VersionDate = new SoapVar($VersionDate, XSD_STRING);

$result2 = $client->GetMakes($SubmitData);
```

Same error each time. I do not know how to get around "Invalid enum value" error

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it's a simple typo: according to the error, `UsedCars` is not a valid value for `VehicleClass`. In your first snippet (that works?) you used `UsedCar` (without the `s`). Can that be it?

Comment: OMG, I can't believe it. Thank you, thank you, thank you. I have been banging my head against the wall. The form from the previous page had the plural spelling

Comment: Can you enter that as an answer and I will mark it as correct?

Comment: You're very welcome - glad it was something simple! Since it's a typo, it's unlikely to be very helpful to others so I'm going to vote to close this question - seems the right thing to do. Again, thanks!